# Adding footers to existing pdf documents using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I was wondering if anyone knew how to add text to an existing pdf document using iTextSharp. I know this question has been asked before but I am trying to add a footer to certain pages in the bottom right hand corner of the document, none of the other posts have helped me and I cannot find any solid info on it elsewhere.

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a footer is done using `PdfStamper` and the `GetOverContent()` method. See [TwoPasses.cs](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/566/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter06/TwoPasses.cs) for an example. For more info on this example, please read [chapter 6](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) of my book.

Note that the example assumes that the pages are of size A4 and that the lower-left corner has the coordinate x=0,y=0. You say you have found other answers (tell us where), but that they didn't help (tell us why not). A common mistake you may have found while searching for an answer is to make the wrong assumptions about the `MediaBox` and the `CropBox` of the existing PDFs. Unfortunately, you're not telling us what you've tried (and as a result you risk that your question will be closed).

Comment: I really have not tried much because I can only find examples of people trying to add an extra page or an annotation to the document, which is not what I am looking for. These examples used itextsharp with pdfstamper and getovercontent(), but I could not find a way to get text to show up at certain coordinates on each page. Anyway thank you for the help, I will look into these examples and see what I can do